# Adding text to image with flexbox

Tags: html, css, image, text, flexbox

I'm looking to add text to various flexbox items.

I'm trying to do some basic level replication from this site, https://lolskinshop.com/product-category/lol-skins/ as a project.

The problem I'm running into is when adding in the text block div onto the image, it's moving the image or is sitting below or to the sides.

I've attached my Codepen example for ease of reading.
https://codepen.io/ralbach/pen/gObOZor

```
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}

h1 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: calibri;
}

h3 {
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: calibri;
}
.nav-links {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-grow: .8;
}

.nav-links li{
  padding: 0px 20px;
}

.nav-links li a{
  transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;
}

.nav-links li a:hover {
color: yellow;
}


li, a{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

nav { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-flow: space-between;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1); 
  align-items: center;
  padding: 30px 10% 30px 10%;
  order: 1;
}

.logo {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: auto;
  order: 3;
}

.champs{
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  cursor: pointer;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 1px 10px 10px 1px;
}

.champ-boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  color: rgba(255,0,255, .9);

}
img{
  opacity: .45;
}
img:hover {
  opacity:1.0;
}
.champ-word{
    position: relative;  
    left: 50%;                       
    top: 50%;                        
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
}
```

````
<head>  
</head> 

<nav>
  <img class="logo" src=" https://lolskinshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/Lolskinshop.com-logo.png" alt="lolskinshop logo">

  <ul class="nav-links">
    <li> <a href="#"> Home </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Skins </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Champions </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Matchup </a></li>
    <li> <a href="#"> About </a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>  
 <body> 
 <div>
  <h1>Divisions</h1>
  <h3>Find your favorite skin sorted alphabetically below! From Aatrox to Zyra, we have them all!
 </div>


<div class="champ-boxes">
  <ul class="champs">
    <li> <img href="#" src="https://lolskinshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/jinx-ambitious-elf-300x545.png">
    </li>  
      <li> <img href="#" src="https://lolskinshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/jinx-ambitious-elf-300x545.png">
    </li>
        <li> <img href="#" src="https://lolskinshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/jinx-ambitious-elf-300x545.png">
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="champs">
    <li>
   <img href="#" src="https://lolskinshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/caitlyn-arcade-300x545.jpg">
      <div class="champ-word">
    Caitlyn</div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <img href="#" src="https://lolskinshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/caitlyn-arcade-300x545.jpg"><div class="champ-word">
    Caitlyn</div>
    </li>

    <li><img href="#" src="https://lolskinshop.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/10/caitlyn-arcade-300x545.jpg">
    <div class="champ-word">
    Caitlyn</div>
    </li>
  </ul>
    </div> 

</body>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to add position relative to the li and position absolute to the copy.

Comment: Example codepen is here https://codepen.io/allisona/pen/GRgRzqE